# How to get my claims in my acess token when using the new SPA IdentityServer template for Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using the following guide to setting up a default IdentityServer4 Angular project: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I want to make a request to a controller endpoint with this, and obtain the user's id (stored in the database) when doing that.

The quickest way to do that is apparently to put the user's id in the JWT token as a claim, I tried doing that using an IProfileService. It looks like this:

```
 public class CustomClaimProfileService: IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CustomClaimProfileService(IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subId =  context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subId);
        var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

        var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();
        claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();
        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Id, user.Id));

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;

    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;
    }
}
```

Adding the service as my last service in ConfigureServices like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomClaimProfileService>();
```

I wanted to use the AddProfileService<>() method I've seen reports of working better, but it's not working even when I put both using IdentityServer4 in my file and have the IdentityServer4 nuget package, so not sure what the problem is there.

I've seen reports of people saying AddTransient like that should work too if you put it at the end though.

Now trying to access the claim like this:

```
        // POST: api/PracticeSession
    [HttpPost]
    public InitialPracticeRequestResult Post([FromBody] InitialPracticeRequest request)
    {
        var idClaim = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();

        if (idClaim != null)
        {
            return initialSessionRequestHandler.InitializePracticeSession(request, idClaim.Value);
        }

        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

The user's claims are empty, I checked with the debugger and it seems GetProfileDataAsync is not getting called.

So now I read that before a claim actually gets put into the token, you need to list that claim as one of the claims that should be in the token when defining the resource, according to docs http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/identity_resource.html .

This is the main question I have right now: how would I go about doing this for this template?

According to the ms docs above about the AddIdentityServerJWT() method called in Startup.cs:

> AddIdentityServerJwt
>   This helper method configures a policy scheme for the app as the default authentication handler. The policy is configured to let Identity handle all requests routed to any subpath in the Identity URL space "/Identity". The JwtBearerHandler handles all other requests. Additionally, this method registers an <>API API resource with IdentityServer with a default scope of <>API and configures the JWT Bearer token middleware to validate tokens issued by IdentityServer for the app.

Now as far as I can see in IdentityServer4 docs, the claims to be put in the token for a resource need to be defined together with the resource itself. As far as I can see, this helper method already defined the resource for me, so then how do I define the claims I need in my token? Am I looking in the right place?

Thanks